# Opentip read table td element title attribute and display as content

Tags: jquery, prototype, opentip

```
<table id="universal-radio-program" title="Uzej ar pelīti uz nosaukumu, lai redzētu aprakstu...">
        <thead>
        <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">Pirmdiena</th><th scope="col">Otrdiena</th><th scope="col">Tre&scaron;diena</th><th scope="col">Ceturtdiena</th><th scope="col">Piektdiena</th><th scope="col">Sestdiena</th><th scope="col">Svētdiena</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>00</td>
        <td title="Dance / Hands Up, Trance, New Tunes..." rowspan="2" colspan="4">Prepare for Morning</td>
        <td title="Presents by Universal Radio X selection...">Take The Chance Of Dance with Universal Radio</td>
        <td title="Universal Radio DJ Team Lives...">URDT Live Sets</td>
        <td title="Universal Radio DJ Team Lives...">&nbsp;</td>
        <td><strong>00</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>01</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>02</td>
        <td title="Progressive, Trance, Techtrance, Hard Trance tunes...">Trance Edition!</td>
        <td title="Progressive, Trance, Techtrance, Hard Trance tunes...">&nbsp;</td>
        <td title="Progressive, Trance, Techtrance, Hard Trance tunes...">&nbsp;</td>
        <td title="Progressive, Trance, Techtrance, Hard Trance tunes...">&nbsp;</td>
        <td title="Progressive, Trance, Techtrance, Hard Trance tunes...">&nbsp;</td>
        <td title="Progressive, Trance, Techtrance, Hard Trance tunes...">&nbsp;</td>
        <td title="Progressive, Trance, Techtrance, Hard Trance tunes...">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>02</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr><th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
        <td>Pirmdiena</td>
        <td>Otrdiena</td>
        <td>Tre&scaron;diena</td>
        <td>Ceturtdiena</td>
        <td>Piektdiena</td>
        <td>Sestdiena</td>
        <td>Svētdiena</td>
        <th>&nbsp;</th></tr>
        </tfoot>
        </table>
```

Here is some example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Hwb2S/1/

And i want to Opentip read table `td` element title attribute and display as grouping opentip content. And remove default title attribute.

My prefer adapter is **prototype**, but also can be **jquery**.

All about **opentip**: http://www.opentip.org

Please update in **jsfiddle**, with your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to why you couldn't just convert these into title tags that Opentip recognizes. You've done 90% of the work, actually. Just make a small tweak and you're there

```
<td data-ot="Progressive, Trance, Techtrance, Hard Trance tunes...">Trance Edition!</td>
```

Comment: Why should one use a non standard attribute? A tooltip library should use the title attribute. It could dynamically remove the title attribute so that browsers don't render them. Older browsers or browsers without Javascript still show the tooltips.

Comment: They have a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/enyo/opentip). You should suggest this there. I can only suggest what works with it as it's written